# Много процессов PhpStorm?

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

После запуска PhpStorm, в процессах такое количество данной программы (скриншот), хотя открыто только две вкладки.

Почему так и как это исправить?

Таких процессов более 50.

[image: Много процессов PhpStorm на Linux]

Comment: Судя по всему, это просто потоки и исправлять ничего не надо.

Comment: Это потоки, а не процессы

Comment: @etki но шторм нагружает на 3+ гр ОЗУ, это наверное не нормально.

Comment: @Fitstd удали из шторма неиспользуемые расширения. Наверняка там много плагинов, которые не используются.

Comment: Эм, почему это ненормально-то?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский плагины чуть решили проблему, стало 2 гб. Спасибо.

Comment: На Линухе занимаемая штормом память от 800 Мб - норма. Я до такого значения себе понижал за счет урезания плагинов.... Еще на это может влиять то, за чем шторм следит, за какими папками и какого объема данные там валяются. Если файлик с массивом в 10000 элементов, может тоже в память загрузить, чтобы индексировать и отслеживать изменения в нём. Поэтому порой полезно не весь проект добавлять в шторм, а некоторым папкам делать `exclude`.  Чтоб он не индексировал их. Хотя точно не уверен про exclude

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё нормально, это потоки, а не процессы.